# Maven build errors

Tags: hibernate, maven-3

Hi I am trying to install Hibernate v4.0.0.CR2 on my desktop machine and it requires Maven to operate.

I set up the required environment variables for Maven and am trying to build maven from the command line. When I run the command 'mvn 3.0.3' in command prompt from the bin directory in Maven (which is on my desktop) I get the error:

```
 D:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin>mvn
 3.0.3 [INFO] Scanning for projects... [ERROR] The build could not read
 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR]   The project
 org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 (D:\Documents and
 Settings\user\Desktop\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\pom.xml) has 4  errors
 [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for
 org.hibernate:hibernate-core:j ar is missing. @ line 18, column 21
 [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for
 javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar is missing. @ line 24, column 21 [ERROR]
 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar is
 missing. @ line 30, column 21 [ERROR]    
 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javassist:javassist:jar is mis
 sing. @ line 36, column 21 [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace
 of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit ch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven
 using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For
 more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea d
 the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
 gException D:\Documents and
 Settings\user\Desktop\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin>
```

My POM.xml file is in the bin directory in Maven:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>First Hibernate Tutorial</name>

     <build>
          <!-- we dont want the version to be part of the generated war
 file name -->
          <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
     </build>

     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Because this is a web app, we also have a dependency on
 the servlet api. -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
             <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here
 use the simple backend -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <!-- Hibernate gives you a choice of bytecode providers
 between cglib and javassist -->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javassist</groupId>
             <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies> </project>
```

I am following the Hibernate tutorial on the website to get a feel for Hibernate to be used at work however I've stumbled upon this problem.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

1. Hibernate doesn't require Maven. Maven is just a build tool.
2. The command to run Maven is `mvn`, not `mvn 3.0.3`.
3. As the error is telling you, you must supply a version for every dependency. In other words, along with `<groupId>` and `<artifactId>`, you must specify a `<version>` element.